# Weekly cron executing 2 times:

Tags: linux, debian, cron, debian-squeeze

I have placed a .sh file that runs a php script weekly.

This script should run only once, but every sunday it runs at:

- 1:30 am
- 6:50 am

Any way to fix this?

## OH CRAP

in the first email the user agent that request that email via web is: `[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Lynx/2.8.5rel.1 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/1.4.4`

and guess who is the IP of the REQUEST ? it's the IP of my old server (where was setted the same cron job)

It's like the old server is requesting that cron via web, I just need to delete the cron job to my old server

Comment: can you post the cron you have setup?

Comment: @pablo: done...

Comment: In addition, please post the contents of /etc/crontab, which should define the schedule for run-parts.

Comment: @beans: done....  (i never edit that file, it comes from debian 6)

Comment: Well the 6:50 time is specified in the crontab file, so that one makes sense. The 1:30 time isn't. Is someone's personal crontab running the program in question (or executing some other part)?

Comment: Can you list all users crontabs?

Comment: @egrorgry: how?

Comment: `crontab -l username`. If you have a lot of users this can be a pain but easily scripted if you need help with it comment back.

Comment: @egro: i have 2 user: root and me :)

Comment: @egro: anyway: `crontab -l`: no crontab for root, `crontab -u myuser -l`: no crontab for myuser. I don't think there are other users

Comment: @yes123: what does the output of `sudo atq` have to say ?

Comment: @lain: nothing.

Comment: what evidence is there that the script is running twice?

Comment: at the end of the script it sends me an email, every sunday i got 2 emails

Comment: You might put a `ps -jHF` and `env` in your job to show the process tree and environtment for the job.  That might help you find what's starting it.

Comment: Check your cron logs (/var/cron/log or similar) to see what is causing this behaviour.

Comment: @shaun: Didn't find any cron logs, searched in `/var/cron/` and `/var/log/`

Comment: @beans: in my job? Do you mean in my .sh file? After `#!/bin/bash` ?

Comment: Yes.  In the shell script.  Anywhere after `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @beans: Considering is a cron if I put it there I don't think I can see the results.. (or it's automatically logged?) But anyway I think I can put it in my .php script (exec()) because as I said my .php script sends me an email with all the output.. should I do sudo too for running the commmand as root?  (anyway +1 for the help)

Comment: output from a cron job should be mailed to the user.  Check your user's mail.  It looks like your crontab is set up to run the weekly job as root.

Comment: I don't think any emails is associated with the user/root. Anyway I have put those command in my php script with exec. Next time they will run i will recevie the output in my email

Comment: @beans: after 1 week the emails have been both arrivide normally :D I updated the first post with the output of your command in email :)

Comment: Is that the entire output of the ps command and the env command?  Looks like you've truncated the output a bit.  Is your 1:27 output really from apache?  If so, I'd be looking at your apache access logs.  Perhaps your mysterious cron job is executed from apache via a request from another machine.

Comment: @bean: I edited the first post (separated the 2 cmd output). Anyway consider I took the output via my php script (saved the output of `exec("");`) I don't have apache access log, but I think I can save the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to check if the script is executed via HTTP or by CLI php (but sincerly i don't think someone run that script via HTTP) +1 for help anyway

Comment: the `exec` php call stores multiline output in an array.. Looks like you are just printing the first record of that array, so your output is truncated.  Try using print_r.  One last thing, how is it possible that apache is not logging?  Have you turned it off?

Comment: @beans oh crap you right, i thought the return string of exec would have all the output.. Now we have to wait next week doh

Comment: no you dont.. you can change the system's clock.. you can modify your cron job to execute in the next minute.. these might be helpful things to try anyway.

Comment: can't change system time because some functions need it, anyway I think can move my shell script in the daily cron..

Comment: @beans: oh sh*t. The first email is executed from Apache2, the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is setted. O_O Please check the first post i updated it O_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job is being run by Apache at 1:27, not cron:

```
ps: www-data  9385  2405  2405  2405  0 47638 12984   1 Mar08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

env: APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2
```

Is httpd being restarted around that time?  (Some startup code could be running this.)  Alternately, does www-data have a crontab?

Comment: nope httpd isn't restarted. And how can I check www-data crontaqb?

Comment: There would usually be a file named /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data, or just use the following to edit their crontab:  sudo crontab -u www-data -e

Comment: @paul: I added the full command output in first post. As you stated the cron of 1:27 is requested with the REQUEST_URI setted, like someone requested it via web (impossibile) How Can I solve this? [in crontabs there are 0 file]

Comment: Check your HTTPD access.log and error.log for that time period.  (Probably under /var/log/apache/)  I don't think you have anything nefarious going on here, probably just some additional automation.  For instance, a backup job could be calling it as a pre-backup task.

Comment: I don't have any backup, this was a clean debian installation (from ovh) and i have installed only apache-php-mysql =/

Comment: Anything showing in the error.log or access.log?  access.log should get you the IP of whatever is requesting the cronweek.php page

Comment: finally thaanks to your suggest we got this. the ip requesting is the same ip of my old server (where was setted the same cronjob) he is requesting via web that page! FAIL xD

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will be relevant..

> Under ubuntu or debian, you can view
>   crontab by /var/spool/cron/crontab/
>   and then a file for each user is in
>   there. That's only for user specific
>   crontab's of course

By the way i got that from here....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users